# SharePoint reporting on permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I wanted to get a report of all the users in SharePoint and know what permissions each user has. I am trying to track down each user permission level for every site they have so I can identify if they have the right permission or not. Is there a way we can get an Excel report to see all the users associated in SharePoint and their permission level and site name?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not a way to do this OOTB in SharePoint. However, Adnan Amin created a PowerShell script that will list all users with their permissions for all sites, lists, items and export it as a CSV so you can view it with Excel, etc. Download the script at:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Access-Report-ac5e8235

Answer (score -1):

Disclamer: I work for Sharegate.

We released a report in our app exactly for that. It's called the Permissions Matrix Report: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharegate-sharepoint-office-365-security-improved